# force MySQLdb to treat all MySQL data as strings

Tags: python, mysql-python

I have a `VARCHAR` field which occasionally stores numbers (random string with only numbers, rarely). When I `SELECT` the field, `MySQLdb` converts that field on that row to an integer, sometimes creating an overflow.

I know that `MySQLdb.connect()` takes a parameter called `conv` which overrides the default MySQL string result --> Python datatype conversion. I don't know, however, how to override it to return all MySQL data as strings.

How do I override the `conv` argument of `MySQLdb.connect()` to return all data from MySQL as a Python string? Are there any alternative solutions?

Comment: use `MySQLdb.converters`, it contains Bool2Str, Set2Str....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html#some-mysql-examples), `conv` is a dictionary between the field type (`MySQLdb.constants.FIELD_TYPE`) and a Python data type. For your example, you could have:

```
from MySQLdb.constants import FIELD_TYPE
conv = { FIELD_TYPE.VARCHAR: str }
```

Or more generally (though a bit more of a hack):

```
from collections import defaultdict #if on Python 3
conv = defaultdict(lambda: str)
```

To force all data types to be converted to `str`.